# Bing maps using elastic search clustering

Tags: elasticsearch, bing-maps

Is there a way to translate elastic search geohashes to bing maps push pins with the appropriate zoom level?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a geohash represents an area. A zoom level would vary based on the size of the map. If the map is small, the zoom level to show that area may be say 10, but to if the map is large, you may have to zoom in to level 12 so that the map is tight around the specified area.

If using the high precision request, parsing the bounding box would be fairly easy. top_left and botton_right are strings that have latitude and longitude separated by a space. Parse these into their individual numbers and create Bing Maps Location objects out of them. Then use the LocationRect.fromCorners or fromLocations function to create a bounding box in Bing Maps. You can then pass this into the bounds option when using the maps setView option. If you want to add a pushpin to the center of the bounding box, us the LocationRect's center property and create a pushpin and add it to the map like you normally would.